# How to Fix : The following error was encountered: Zero Sized Reply Squid did not receive any data for this request

Tags: jsp, servlets

My Aplication is Jsp/Servlet when i fire url then proceed after 2-3 minute it will give below error.

**The following error was encountered: Zero Sized Reply  Squid did not receive any data for this request**

can anybody help me in this?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the code of your Jsp/servlet? Which is the version of Squid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual problem it is regarding firefox did not get responce of perticular request so it will throws timeout.

**Solution**

Write about:config in firefox Url

and paste line

network.http.connection-timeout;

and paste your URL in setting of firefox

Comment: Kind of incomplete your answer, don't you think, Sejal? Paste line? Which line? Which value? `network.http.connection-timeout;` is a key that already has a value.. what should be configured for this key? (...)

Comment: @ivanleoncz set value of this key. this is not incomplete ans.